# Export normilized image without reconverting?

Tags: python, image, numpy, computer-vision, data-science

I have the following code to normilize pixel values of an image in the range 0-1.

```
# Import
simpsons = Image.open("simps.png")
simpsons_pixels = np.asarray(simpsons)

# Normalize
simpsons_pixels = simpsons_pixels.astype('float32')
simpsons_pixels /= 255.0

# Denormalize
simpsons_pixels *= 255
simpsons_pixels = simpsons_pixels.astype('uint8')

# Export
simpsons_before = Image.fromarray(simpsons_pixels, 'L')
simpsons_before.save("simpsons_before.png")
```

Is it possible to export an image without having to change its values back to the range 0-255 and/or converting it back to int?

Comment: Some file formats like TIFF support floating-point pixel values. But most software doesn’t recognize such TIFF files. I know that using [DIPlib](https://pypi.org/project/diplib/) (I’m an author) reading and writing floating-point pixel data is trivial (either in TIFF or ICS format).